# Mac WebDAV Connection Read-Only Issue on Windows Server 2008 WebDAV Folder

Tags: mac, iis-7, windows-server-2008, webdav

I set up Windows Server 2008 (x64) and installed the WebDAV extension to IIS 7 (also x64) and created a WebDAV share.  I also created a self-signed certificate and enabled HTTPS on the box - requiring HTTPS to connect to the WebDAV share.

I can connect to the system via Vista and connect to the "network folder" just fine.  I'm able to connect, create and delete files and folders.

Trying to connect via Mac OS-X, however, I can connect to the WebDAV share, but I only have read-only access.  I can't create or delete any files and folders, even though I'm signed in with the same username/password that I used on the Vista box.

What am I missing?

*Update 2008/09/17 - Feedback from a colleague is that Mac OS-X refuses to open as Read/Write unless it sees a WebDAV 2.0 server that supports LOCK methods (RFC 2518)?  Investigating that now...

Comment: That would explain why my server didn't work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OS X Finder request DAV Level 2 support, that is, a working LOCK extension. Without that the share will be mounted read-only.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue connecting to a WebDAV server I wrote - Ithink OS X is a bit picky about the server not providing all of the required functionality, and will only connect as Read Only.

I wound up using cadaver instead.  No GUI, but allows for file transfers.